Cannot see any changes i made in the cshtml file on browser
I'm a newbie in programming (17 y.o), and I am currently struggling with ASP.NET. When I create a .cshtml file and try to test it in the browser, I see the default interface that Microsoft provides. How can I make my project show me all my changes in the index.cshtml file?
I tried to make the webUI project to be a startup project, but it did not helped me on my problem.

can you provide us with more info. what do you use (web app or SPA with blazor ) ?
how did you structure the project  ? did you use the default visual studio template ? did you configure the project correctly (like configuring the router ) ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

start with a asp.net core web app (Model-View-Controller) follow a turotial and that should get you started with cshtml / c# / razor
